# Error: surf plot: Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector

Tags: matlab

I want to have a 2-D color map plot, with following code, but it keeps returning me this error, could anyone help me

```
x = 0:100:600;

z = 0:100:600;

[X,Z] = meshgrid(x,z);

for z2 = 3:5;

    for x2 = 3:5
        E1 = Z(z2);
        E2 = X(x2);
        E = E1 +E2;
    end
end



figure;

surf(X,Z,E,'EdgeColor','None');

view(2);

xlabel('x','fontsize',20);

ylabel('z','fontsize',20);

colormap jet;
```

Comment: Your variable `E` has to have the same size as `X` and `Z`. How do you want to calculate `E`? Is it `Z + X`?

Comment: I suggest checking your syntax against the actual syntax of [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need an `E` entry for each `X` and `Z` entry to have a valid surface because you need a "height" for each x/y location.

In your example, `E` is simply a scalar whereas `X` and `Z` contain many values. It seems like you'd want to do something like:

```
E = Z + X;

surf(X, Z, E, 'EdgeColor', 'none')
```

If instead you want a plane at a given height (`E`), then make `Z` a matrix where all values are equal to `E`.

```
surf(X, Z, zeros(size(X)) + E, 'EdgeColor', 'none')
```

If you only want to plot a subset, you can do something like:

```
[X, Z] = meshgrid(x(3:5), z(3:5));
surf(X, Z, X + Z, 'EdgeColor', 'None')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering me! so I took your advice and plotted zeros(size(X)) + E, but the problem is that matlab only takes the last value of E in the for loop, and stick it in the matrix "zeros(size(X))", hence I got a plot with the exact same values everywhere. Therefore how do I plot E with everyvalues of E returned by the for loop?

Comment: @LinQiao Well as you have your loop written, you overwrite `E` every time through the loop. Did you try the first option I've provided? That should give you the value of `E` each time through the loop (without the loop)

Comment: Yes, but I want to only use the third, fourth and fifth element in X and Z, which means, I want to use 200,300 and 400 only for plotting E. So if I say E = Z(z2) + X(x2), it still returns in the same error? How can I do it? Thanks very much!

Comment: @LinQiao Updated with an example of how you would do that.